# Which cards should I sleeve for The 7th Continent?

Tags: the-7th-continent

I backed *The 7th Continent* on Kickstarter and received 200 card sleeves with my order. There are far more than 200 cards in the game. Which cards are worth sleeving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cards in your action and hand deck are used the most, and these are the ones the for which the sleeves were provided ("to protect all ACTION and STATE cards"). These include the following:

- 11 character cards
- 35 character-specific skill cards
- 35 skill cards
- 49 advanced skill cards, or 50 if you have the *Path of Repentance* expansion
- 11 curse cards (including the four "Death is Lurking" cards)
- 45 state cards. These are found at these numbers:

  > 100 to 108, inclusive (5 of each)

For a total of 186 cards, or 187 with the *Path of Repentance* expansion.

The following are other possible candidates:

- 10 saving-related cards
- Satchel & Journal
- 7 clue cards
- Card 777 ("Easy mode") and card 650 ("Hardcode mode")

For a total of 20 cards.

The counts are for the base Kickstarter reward. Cards from the add-ons are mentioned separately.

Comment: 49 is the correct number. I was suspicious of that count too, so I did a double check against the official [card list](https://the7thcontinent.seriouspoulp.com/documents/t7c/The7thContinent_cards-list.pdf) when I wrote my post. There are 40 in the base game, and 3 in each of the incl expansions. Do you perhaps have the _Path of Repentance_ expansion add-on? It adds one.

Comment: I do have a few expansions, but haven't added them yet. I think I'm missing *Path of Repentance*. Your post said that it was for "the Kickstarter reward with no add-ons", so I assumed that meant no expansions. If you are including expansions (which would be helpful for anybody sleeving those), it may be better to divide it up by base game and expansion pack.

Comment: Then I'd have to start worrying about KS-exclusive content (e.g. some of the character cards, some skill or advanced skill cards) for a game that's never going to be published outside of KS.

Comment: From the official card list it looks like there are 40 in the base game, 3 in The Icy Maze, 3 in The Forbidden Sanctuary, 3 in Swamp of Madness, and 1 in Path of Repentance. So if a player hasn't added any of those to their base game yet, then they'll have only 40.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting more sleeves for the game you just need some that are "premium thickness" in the 80 X 80 mm size cards, there are several companies that make them including Swan and Mayday.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of which cards I should sleeve with the sleeves I have.